How to launch a C++ code in a cluster with gnu parallel with different values of parameter
I am a medium level coder efficient with handling c++ codes; however, my knowledge of BASH script and gnu parallel is very minimal. I am particularly interested in modifying a c++ code that numerically solves a discretized partial differential equation (more specifically, Gross-Pitaevskii equation). The code is given below:
//
#define __STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__ 1

#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<cmath>
#include<random>
#include<iomanip>
#include"Eigen/Dense"
#include"Eigen/SVD"
#include<fstream>
#include<complex>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

#define Pi 3.1415926535897

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
const Complex I(0, 1);

unordered_map<string,string> process_arguments(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string delimiter = "=";
    unordered_map<string,string> dict;
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        string str = string(argv[i]);
        size_t pos = str.find(delimiter);
        string name = str.substr(0,pos);
        string value = str.substr(pos+1);
        dict.insert(make_pair(name,value));
    }
    return dict;
}

/*
Other user-defined functions relevant to the algorithm of the differential equation solving
*/


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
 //Code-block that helps the user read a particular file from a different directory
        string folder = "";
        if (argc >1)
        {
            cout<<"Trying to load the file \n";
            unordered_map<string,string> args = process_arguments(argc,argv);
                for (std::pair<string, string> element : args)
                {
                   if (element.first=="folder")
                   {
                       folder = element.second;
                   }
                }
        }

// inputting the value of parameters
    double m_tilde=1.0/10.0, G_tilde=-0.1, gamma=0.1; //control parameters
    double delta_t=0.001, delta_x = (1.0/30.0),t_init=36.7; //time and space_steps
    Complex mult1 = (0.25*I*delta_t*(1.0+m_tilde))/(delta_x*delta_x), mult2 = (0.5*delta_t*I), mult3;
    complex<double> V_0(0.5*sqrt(1+m_tilde),0.0),V=0.522631+I*0.0;//velocity
    int Length=600,i; //system size
    int space_points = int(Length/delta_x);//calculating number of spatial and temporal points on the 2D grid
    double err_iter = 10e-9, err_config = 10e-5;
    cout<<"G: "<<G_tilde<<" delta_t: "<<delta_t<<" delta_x: "<<delta_x<<" Length: "<<Length<<" m_tilde: "<<m_tilde<<" V_0/v: "<<real(V_0)<<endl;
    
    clock_t start, end;//time measurement
    start = clock();

//Enter the main code
/*defining more matrices and vectors to help with the code*/

//reading the initial configuration file
    char filename_input_Phi[200];
    ifstream input_Phi;

//taking Phi

sprintf(filename_input_Phi,"Phi_solution_herm_G%gm%gV%gtime%gdt%gdx%gL%d_finite_difference.dat",G_tilde,m_tilde,real(V_0),t_init,delta_t,delta_x,Length);
    input_Phi.open((folder+filename_input_Phi).c_str());
    if ((!input_Phi)) {
        cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
        abort();
      }
    
    double temp_phi;

    for(i=0; i<3*space_points; ++i)
    {
      input_Phi>>temp_phi;
      if(i%3==1)
      Phi_init_real(i/3) = temp_phi+0.0*I;
      if(i%3==2)
      Phi_init_imag(i/3) = temp_phi + 0.0*I;
    }
    Phi_init = Phi_init_real + I*Phi_init_imag;
    cout<<"Initial Phi is"<<endl<<Phi_init<<endl;
    
    
    /*Creating output files and solving the differential equation numerically*/
  
    end = clock();//time measurement stopped
    double time_taken = double(end-start)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    cout<< "Time taken by the program is "<<time_taken/60.0<< " mins "<<endl;
    return 0;
}

As one can see, In this code, I am first defining certain numerical parameters; the relevant ones being m_tilde, G_tilde, t_init, V_0 and V_init. Using these values, I create a filename and assign it to the char type variable filename_input_Phi. Then the code reads a file with the given name from a directory that I mention in my job launching script (mentioned later in the question) and proceeds to solve the rest of the code. Note that in the code snippet that I have provided, I only show the parts relevant to my upcoming queries. If any user would like to see the full code, please let me know and I will update it with the full code. I also don't do any threading or parallelization in my code, even though my code uses Eigen library.
Currently, I am running multiple simulations using this code in a cluster managed by SLURM. I compile the code using g++ to create an .exe file with name like GPE.out. And then I submit this job to the cluster using the following SLURM submission script:
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=GrossP_opti_contd
#SBATCH --output=check_var_%A_contd1.txt
#SBATCH --mail-type=END,FAIL
#SBATCH --partition=multi248
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -w cn17 ##node_name
#SBATCH --time=2-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mail-user=email_id
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=512 ##0.5GB

srun ./GPE.out folder=/path/to/directory/ ## this is where I put the directory path from where the input of filename_input_Phi[200] is read 

I am doing multiple simulations with varying the values of the parameters that I have mentioned above. Currently I manually input a set of values and compile separately every time I have to launch a simulation. However, recently I came to know that there is a shell tool called GNU parallel that is very adept at handling this sort of problem. I have the following question:
Can anyone guide me in writing a job submission code using gnu parallel that will read the initial parameter values from a data file like below:
m_tilde G_tilde t_init V_0 V_init

0.1     0.1      10     1    2

0.3     0.3      10     1    4

0.5      1       20     2    1

And for each set of parameters, launch a separate simulation in the cluster, all the jobs at the same time? The jobs should be independent and don't need to communicate to each other while during the running course of the simulation.

Sounds like you may want to use a slurm array job eg https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html. This starts multiple jobs, each with an integer, a job array index. you can use this index to extract a different row of your input data.
